# How to match records that are associated with a specific set of other records?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to add to two different search variations to my project.
There is a model "User" and a model "Tag". A User has many Tags.
Now I want to be able to search the Users with specific Tags.
Either I want to show all Users that has any of the specified tags.
I got this working this way:

```
$query = $this->Users->find();
$query->matching('Tags', function ($q) {
    return $q->where(['Tags.name' => 'Tag1'])
             ->orWhere(['Tags.name' => 'Tag2']);
});
```

But now I want to find all Users that have both Tags at the same time.
I tried `->andWhere` instead of `->orWhere`, but the result is always empty.

How can I find Users that contain multiple Tags?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve this, one would be to group the results and use `HAVING` to compare the count of the distinct tags

```
$query = $this->Users
    ->find()
    ->matching('Tags', function ($query) {
        return $query->where(['Tags.name IN' => ['Tag1', 'Tag2']]);
    })
    ->group('Users.id')
    ->having([
        $this->Users->query()->newExpr('COUNT(DISTINCT Tags.name) = 2')
    ]);
```

This will select only those users that have two distinct tags, which can only be `Tag1` and `Tag2` since these are the only ones that are being joined in. In case the `name` column is unique, you may count on the primary key instead.

The `IN` btw. is essentially the same as your `OR` conditions (the database system will expand `IN` to `OR` conditions accordingly).

Comment: Sorry, took me a while. But works perfect!
Thanks a lot!