# Cakephp 3 search tags

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

From Cakebook we got this working example:

```
public function findTagged(Query $query, array $options) {
  return $this->find()
    ->distinct(['Articles.id'])
    ->matching('Tags', function ($q) use ($options) {
    if (empty($options['tags'])) {
        return $q->where(['Tags.title IS' => null]);
    }
    return $q->where(['Tags.title IN' => $options['tags']]);
  });
}
```

For example, with address articles/tagged/test/new, it will find articles with tag "test" OR tag "new". I would like to modify this code in CakePHP way, to get articles with tag "test" AND tag "new".

Have you got any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938440/how-to-match-records-that-are-associated-with-a-specific-set-of-other-records**

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tags/wiki/Notes) using find(tagged) and friendsofcake/search plugin :)

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the solution for your Question :** Update your finder Query as below -

```
public function findTagged(Query $query, array $options){
     $this->opt = $options['tags'];
     $articles = $this->find()
        ->select(['Articles.id', 'Articles.url', 'Articles.title', 'Articles.description'])
        ->matching('Tags', function ($query) {
            return $query->where(['Tags.title IN' =>$this->opt]);
        })->group(['Articles.id'])
        ->having([
            $this->Users->query()->newExpr('COUNT(DISTINCT Tags.title) = '.count($this->opt))
        ]);

    return $articles;
}
```

> Above Query will return only `matching tags` for the Articles.

Comment: I'd say that the above query will return 'Articles matching the defined tags'. The query won't return 'tags'.

Comment: $this->Users ... How do Users come into play, all of a sudden?