# Get belongsToMany associations based on multiple field values

Tags: php, associations, cakephp-3.0, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have the following situation:

**Destination** belongsToMany **Attributes**

```php
// DestinationsTable.php
$this->belongsToMany('Attributes', [
  'foreignKey' => 'destination_id',
  'targetForeignKey' => 'attribute_id',
  'joinTable' => 'destinations_attributes'
]);

// AttributesTable.php
$this->belongsToMany('Destinations', [
  'foreignKey' => 'attribute_id',
  'targetForeignKey' => 'destination_id',
  'joinTable' => 'destinations_attributes'
]);
```

Now i would like to retrieve all **Destinations that have a (multiple) selection of Attributes**
That shouldn't be very difficult, i thought. It looks like I don't get it...

---

I tried the following but it results in retrieving all Destinations with at least one of the desired Attributes. But I would like the results to reduce after selecting more and more Attributes

```php
$attribute_ids = [104, 117];

$query = $this->Destinations->find();

$query->matching('Attributes', function(\Cake\ORM\Query $q) use ($attribute_ids) {
  return $q->where(['Attributes.id IN' => $attribute_ids]);
});
```

Sometimes it is easier to understand seeing the frontend. Those two Attributes have the `Attributes.id` `104` and `117`.
**Thank you for the help!**

[image: ads]

Comment: Sounds like **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938440/how-to-match-records-that-are-associated-with-a-specific-set-of-other-records/30945582** to me.

Comment: That really worked! Even if it is a strange way to handle it. Thank you