# CakePHP3, request "and" match conditions in php array

Tags: cakephp, request, match

I need your help for a request with `cakephp`.
My simple request is :

```
$goal_to_find = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

My table is like :

```
id | user_id | goal
 1 | 1       | 1
 2 | 1       | 4
 3 | 2       | 7
 4 | 3       | 1
 5 | 3       | 2
 5 | 3       | 3
 5 | 3       | 4
```

My request is :

```
$id_list = $this->mytable->find('list', ['keyField' => 'id', 'valueField' => 'user_id'])->where(['mytable.goal IN' => $goal_to_find]);
```

This request return all records where goal is 1 OR 2 OR 3 OR 4

so I get user_id 1 and 3

but I need to get all user where goal is 1 AND 2 AND 3 AND 4

so in the example I need to get only user_id 3

How can i do this ?

Comment: Sounds similar to **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938440/how-to-match-records-that-are-associated-with-a-specific-set-of-other-records**.

Comment: I already saw the post of conehead but I don't find the solution of my problem with...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the example there will work for the problem that you're showing, you'd just use your normal conditions instead of matching.